Page 1 loses state when its is re directed to Page2 and then back using go_router
What package does this bug report belong to?
go_router
What target platforms are you seeing this bug on?
Android, Web, Windows
Have you already upgraded your packages?
Yes
Dependency versions
pubspec.lock
# Generated by pub
# See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
packages:
  args:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: args
      sha256: "7cf60b9f0cc88203c5a190b4cd62a99feea42759a7fa695010eb5de1c0b2252a"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.5.0"
  async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: async
      sha256: "947bfcf187f74dbc5e146c9eb9c0f10c9f8b30743e341481c1e2ed3ecc18c20c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.11.0"
  boolean_selector:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: boolean_selector
      sha256: "6cfb5af12253eaf2b368f07bacc5a80d1301a071c73360d746b7f2e32d762c66"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.1"
  characters:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: characters
      sha256: "04a925763edad70e8443c99234dc3328f442e811f1d8fd1a72f1c8ad0f69a605"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.0"
  clock:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: clock
      sha256: cb6d7f03e1de671e34607e909a7213e31d7752be4fb66a86d29fe1eb14bfb5cf
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.1"
  collection:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: collection
      sha256: ee67cb0715911d28db6bf4af1026078bd6f0128b07a5f66fb2ed94ec6783c09a
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.18.0"
  connectivity_plus:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: connectivity_plus
      sha256: "2056db5241f96cdc0126bd94459fc4cdc13876753768fc7a31c425e50a7177d0"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.0.5"
  connectivity_plus_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: connectivity_plus_platform_interface
      sha256: "42657c1715d48b167930d5f34d00222ac100475f73d10162ddf43e714932f204"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.1"
  cupertino_icons:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: cupertino_icons
      sha256: ba631d1c7f7bef6b729a622b7b752645a2d076dba9976925b8f25725a30e1ee6
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.8"
  dbus:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: dbus
      sha256: "365c771ac3b0e58845f39ec6deebc76e3276aa9922b0cc60840712094d9047ac"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.7.10"
  fake_async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: fake_async
      sha256: "511392330127add0b769b75a987850d136345d9227c6b94c96a04cf4a391bf78"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.1"
  ffi:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: ffi
      sha256: "16ed7b077ef01ad6170a3d0c57caa4a112a38d7a2ed5602e0aca9ca6f3d98da6"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.3"
  flutter:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  flutter_lints:
    dependency: "direct dev"
    description:
      name: flutter_lints
      sha256: "3f41d009ba7172d5ff9be5f6e6e6abb4300e263aab8866d2a0842ed2a70f8f0c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.0"
  flutter_riverpod:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: flutter_riverpod
      sha256: "0f1974eff5bbe774bf1d870e406fc6f29e3d6f1c46bd9c58e7172ff68a785d7d"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.5.1"
  flutter_test:
    dependency: "direct dev"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  flutter_web_plugins:
    dependency: transitive
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  go_router:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: go_router
      sha256: "48d03a1e4887b00fe622695139246e3c778ac814eeb32421467b56d23fa64034"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "14.2.6"
  leak_tracker:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: leak_tracker
      sha256: "3f87a60e8c63aecc975dda1ceedbc8f24de75f09e4856ea27daf8958f2f0ce05"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "10.0.5"
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: leak_tracker_flutter_testing
      sha256: "932549fb305594d82d7183ecd9fa93463e9914e1b67cacc34bc40906594a1806"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.5"
  leak_tracker_testing:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: leak_tracker_testing
      sha256: "6ba465d5d76e67ddf503e1161d1f4a6bc42306f9d66ca1e8f079a47290fb06d3"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.1"
  lints:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: lints
      sha256: "976c774dd944a42e83e2467f4cc670daef7eed6295b10b36ae8c85bcbf828235"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.0"
  logging:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: logging
      sha256: "623a88c9594aa774443aa3eb2d41807a48486b5613e67599fb4c41c0ad47c340"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.0"
  matcher:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: matcher
      sha256: d2323aa2060500f906aa31a895b4030b6da3ebdcc5619d14ce1aada65cd161cb
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.16+1"
  material_color_utilities:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: material_color_utilities
      sha256: f7142bb1154231d7ea5f96bc7bde4bda2a0945d2806bb11670e30b850d56bdec
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.1"
  meta:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: meta
      sha256: bdb68674043280c3428e9ec998512fb681678676b3c54e773629ffe74419f8c7
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.15.0"
  nm:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: nm
      sha256: "2c9aae4127bdc8993206464fcc063611e0e36e72018696cd9631023a31b24254"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.5.0"
  path:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path
      sha256: "087ce49c3f0dc39180befefc60fdb4acd8f8620e5682fe2476afd0b3688bb4af"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.9.0"
  petitparser:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: petitparser
      sha256: c15605cd28af66339f8eb6fbe0e541bfe2d1b72d5825efc6598f3e0a31b9ad27
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.0.2"
  plugin_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: plugin_platform_interface
      sha256: "4820fbfdb9478b1ebae27888254d445073732dae3d6ea81f0b7e06d5dedc3f02"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.8"
  riverpod:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: riverpod
      sha256: f21b32ffd26a36555e501b04f4a5dca43ed59e16343f1a30c13632b2351dfa4d
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.5.1"
  sky_engine:
    dependency: transitive
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.99"
  source_span:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: source_span
      sha256: "53e943d4206a5e30df338fd4c6e7a077e02254531b138a15aec3bd143c1a8b3c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.10.0"
  stack_trace:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: stack_trace
      sha256: "73713990125a6d93122541237550ee3352a2d84baad52d375a4cad2eb9b7ce0b"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.11.1"
  state_notifier:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: state_notifier
      sha256: b8677376aa54f2d7c58280d5a007f9e8774f1968d1fb1c096adcb4792fba29bb
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.0"
  stream_channel:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: stream_channel
      sha256: ba2aa5d8cc609d96bbb2899c28934f9e1af5cddbd60a827822ea467161eb54e7
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.2"
  string_scanner:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: string_scanner
      sha256: "556692adab6cfa87322a115640c11f13cb77b3f076ddcc5d6ae3c20242bedcde"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.0"
  term_glyph:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: term_glyph
      sha256: a29248a84fbb7c79282b40b8c72a1209db169a2e0542bce341da992fe1bc7e84
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.1"
  test_api:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: test_api
      sha256: "5b8a98dafc4d5c4c9c72d8b31ab2b23fc13422348d2997120294d3bac86b4ddb"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.7.2"
  vector_math:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: vector_math
      sha256: "80b3257d1492ce4d091729e3a67a60407d227c27241d6927be0130c98e741803"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.4"
  vm_service:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: vm_service
      sha256: f652077d0bdf60abe4c1f6377448e8655008eef28f128bc023f7b5e8dfeb48fc
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "14.2.4"
  web:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: web
      sha256: d43c1d6b787bf0afad444700ae7f4db8827f701bc61c255ac8d328c6f4d52062
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.0"
  xml:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: xml
      sha256: b015a8ad1c488f66851d762d3090a21c600e479dc75e68328c52774040cf9226
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.5.0"
sdks:
  dart: ">=3.5.0 <4.0.0"
  flutter: ">=3.19.0"


Steps to reproduce
Run the app
If there is network connection app will go to home page.
On home page I have a listview up to 100 elements.
Now scroll to any element say 50.
And now turn of your platform/system/mobile data connection.
App will be redirected to No Network page.
Now reconnect your network.
Home page will show listview starting from 0 instead of where you left it at 50 as per our example.
Expected results
App should restore state of home page and show listview at element 50.
Actual results
Its is not restoring state of where home page was before redirection.
Code sample
Code sample
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final conectionProvider = StateNotifierProvider<NetworkInfo, bool>((ref) {
  return NetworkInfo();
});

class NetworkInfo extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  NetworkInfo() : super(true) {
    subscribeToConnection();
  }

  late StreamSubscription<List<ConnectivityResult>> _subscription;
  subscribeToConnection() async {
    _subscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((List<ConnectivityResult> result) {
      final ConnectivityResult connected = result.first;
      if (connected != ConnectivityResult.none) {
        state = true;
      } else {
        state = false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

final goRouteProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final connected = ref.watch(conectionProvider);
  return GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const HomeScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/nonetwork',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const LoginScreen(),
      ),
    ],
    redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      if (!connected) {
        return '/nonetwork';
      }
      return null;
    },
  );
});

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(
    child: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  static const String title = 'GoRouter Example: Redirection';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final router = ref.watch(goRouteProvider);
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: title,
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(App.title)),
        body: const Center(
            child: Text('No network connection. Please try again later.')),
      );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(App.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Screenshots or Videos

Screenshots / Video demonstration

Logs
Logs
[Paste your logs here]

Flutter Doctor output
Doctor output
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.4037], locale en-PK)
[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 17.6.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!


Your observation is that the state of the ListView is not preserved when you navigate to another page and back. Due to how flutter manages its widget tree and the state of widgets that is, in fact, the expected result.
You could remove all references to provider and go_router and just have two pages and navigate back and forth and you would see that the state of the listview is not preserved.
Example:
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final random = Random();

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('List view'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index: ${random.nextInt(100000)}'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before),

        //onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),  
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I would recommend having a look at the life-cycle of stateful widgets.
To get a feel for what is going on, you could replace the listview with a custom StatefulWidget which prints a message in initState, build, and dispose.

As a side note: If your listview were to contain stateful widgets these would also be initialized, build, and disposed on demand as they come in and out of view while scrolling (see this question).
If your aim is to preserve the state of the listview this has been already asked, see for example this question.

actually I want to show no internet screen when user gets disconnected. but as soon as they reconnect I wanna show them the same page with same state where there were before diconnection.

Your question is about a bug report with go_router and why the widget state is not preserved during navigation, which has been addressed. I would recommend investigating 'How to preserve widget state', try to make it work, and if you have problems, then post a new question that is focused on those problems.
